# Checking whether a vector layer is empty or not

Tags: pyqgis

I am working on intersections of a number of buffers with one another. When two particular buffers have no intersection, applying intersection function on them produces an empty layer which I want to delete. But how do I check if the intersection result produced is an empty layer or not? Is there any inbuilt function which I can use in my code?

Comment: Check this out: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.selectedFeatureCount

Comment: @Mr.Che, better this one: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.featureCount